# Javascript Calculate Date and Send value to textbox

Tags: javascript, date

I'm having Javascript with this code:

```
function addRowss(frm) {
        var start = new Date(document.myform.bookstart.value);
        var ends = new Date(document.myform.bookend.value);

        var starts = document.myform.bookstart.value;
        var yeara = starts.substring(0, 2);
        var montha = starts.substring(3,6);
        var datea = starts.substring(7,11);
        var num3 = (ends - start)/1000/60/60/24;
        var i;

        for(i=0;i <= num3; i++)
        {                   
            var theday = yeara+'-'+getnumo(montha)+'-'+datea;
            var resday = new Date(theday);
            rowNum ++;
            var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Date: <input type="text" class="datepick" name="qty[]" id="date'+rowNum+'" value="'+theday+'"> Price: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
            jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
            yeara++;
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is text name[] will be automatically filled by my start date to my end date. For example, if I fill '06-Aug-2015' at start input and '06-Sep-2015' at end input, it will result about 30 textbox field which it's value will be filled by its date... so it will result:

```
[2015-08-06][ empty ]
[2015-08-07][ empty ]
[2015-08-08]
...
[2015-09-06][ empty ]
Note: [ ] = textbox
```

Right now I can add many textbox (attachment pic), but I can't set the value of this textbox as I want. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `document.myform.bookstart.value`?

Comment: it depend on my input... it from datepicker. Its format value is "dd-M-yy" or "06 Aug 2015"

Comment: Hi RobG, how to incrementing day by day? Because as You can see at my attachment it will count till 34.

Also I have write Date object (2 first line). Also create a function to make it date (getnumo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a function to parse that format to a Date object, it's a non–standard format so no guarantee that the Date constructor will parse it correctly in all browsers. Then create a function to create a date string from a Date object in the format you require. Now you can generate the rows and just call the functions to add the formatted strings, incrementing the date by one day as you go along.

Here's how I'd rewrite your code to do that, you can get rid of the *rowNum* variable, I've modified the remove listener and function so it's not required.

```js
// '06-Sep-2015' to Date
function parseDMY(s) {
  var months = {jan:0, feb:1, mar:2, apr:3, may:4,  jun:5, jul:6, aug:7, sep:8, oct:9, nov:10, dec:11};
  var b = s.split('-');
  return new Date(b[2],months[b[1].toLowerCase().substring(0,3)],b[0]);
}

// Date to '06-Sep-2015'
function formatDate(date) {
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun', 'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}
  return z(date.getDate()) + '-' + months[date.getMonth()] + '-' + date.getFullYear();
}

function addRows(frm) {
    var start = parseDMY(frm.bookstart.value);
    var ends   = parseDMY(frm.bookend.value);
    var markup = '';
    var num3 = Math.round((ends - start)/8.64e7);
    var rowNum = 0;

    for(var i=0; i <= num3; i++) {
        var theday = formatDate(start);
        ++rowNum;
        markup += '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">Date: <input type="text" class="datepick" name="qty[]" id="date' +
                   rowNum + '" value="' + theday + '"> Price: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="' +
                   frm.add_name.value + '"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(this);"></p>';
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);        
    }
    document.getElementById('itemRows').innerHTML = markup;
}

function removeRow(el) {
  var node = el.parentNode;
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm">
  <table>
   <tr><td>Start date<td><input name="bookstart" value="05-Aug-2015">
   <tr><td>End date<td><input name="bookend" value="08-Aug-2015">
   <tr><td><input name="add_name" value="the name">
   <tr><td><input type="reset"><td><input type="button" value="Add rows" onclick="addRows(this.form)">
  </table>
  <div id="itemRows"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: That was Awesome RobG! Thank You very much!! Just realize I don't create parseDMY. Maybe that's the problem... but thanks for saving my life

Comment: You should use *parseDMY* for the reason outlined: browsers aren't guaranteed to correctly parse the format your passing to the Date constructor. It may work in the browsers you've tested, but there is no specification or standard that requires them to do so.

Comment: I see... Thanks for explanation... Got new experience.... Can I ask once again? Is there any function for reset button for the function? Because I want to remove it. It's ok to remove it right?

Comment: Yes, it just resets the form.